# jquery not working in Joomla 2.5

Tags: jquery, joomla

I'm trying to use jQuery in my Joomla 2.5 site to swap 2 images. I can get it working in a static html page but not in Joomla, this what I'm trying to use in Joomla:http://www.ssdtutorials.com/tutorials/title/change-image-click.html
Would really appreciate someone's help here please,
This my code;

```
<div id="wrapper">

<div id="imageContainer">
<img src="templates/horme2/images/image1.jpg" alt="01" 
width="399" height="299" class="active" />
<img src="templates/horme2/images/image2.jpg" alt="01" 
width="399" height="299" />

 </div>

</div>



* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
 }
body {
 text-align: center;
 font-family: Arial, Verdana, Sans-serif;
 font-size: 12px;
padding: 30px 0;    
}
body,a {
color: #333;
}
#wrapper {
 width: 280px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
#imageContainer {
 width: 280px;
 height: 280px;
 position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
background: #eee;
}
#imageContainer img {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
z-index: 1;
}
#imageContainer img.active {
z-index: 3;
}

<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

var imageObject = {
clickSwap : function(obj) {
    obj.click(function() {
        var activeImage = $(this).children('img.active');
        activeImage.removeClass('active');
        if (activeImage.next().length > 0) {
            activeImage.next().addClass('active');
        } else {
            $(this).children('img:first-child').addClass('active');
        }
        return false;
    });
}
};
$(function() {
imageObject.clickSwap($('#imageContainer'));
});
```

Comment: Is this a static site or are you using Joomla? I only ask cause your code looking nothing like the index.php for a Joomla template. I would suggest reading documentation on how to implement your own code. Do bare in mind you cannot simply add your code to an article, it must be done properly

Comment: Check for any JS errors in FireBug or default object inspector of your browser. Pay attention to errors, which occur on page load - they stop most scripts from working.

Answer (score 0):

I think, that you should place the code in the header part.

This can be done in two ways:

1. In the index.php of your, place the code in the header.
2. If the code is in a specfic extension:

**A. Inline example:**

```
<?php
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addScriptDeclaration('
    window.event("domready", function() {
        alert("An inline JavaScript Declaration");
    });
');
?>
```

**B. File example:**

```
<?php
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addScript('/media/system/js/sample.js');
?>
```

source of code - further information:  http://docs.joomla.org/Adding_JavaScript